# I should be able to tell what a Stack Exchange site is about from its front page, even when logged in

Tags: feature-request, homepage

I'm staring at the front pages of Stack Exchange and Super User.  I'm a member of both, which means there is NOTHING to indicate what either one is for on the front page: no text of any sort describes what the site is about.

Even before I joined, there was like one sentence on Server Fault ... in the entire page full of text.

I know front page space is at a premium, but shouldn't at least one sentence about each Stack Exchange site be visible, *even if you are logged in*?  Just because I logged in to one or the other ages ago does not mean I remember whether to use Server Fault or Super User.

Comment: https://$DOMAIN/help/on-topic Don't think it needs to be on the front-page necessarily.

Comment: They've fixed this for SO at least. If you visit https://stackoverflow.com you won't know what the site is about, whether logged in or not.

Comment: @JJ for Transparency and Monica ... well first off that's quite a name :)  But second, yes, this is less of an issue for Math, and more a problem for "similar" sites like SuperUser and ServerFault (and to a lesser extent StackOverflow even).   A user comes to one of them thinking "I need to ask question X".  But once there, they have no way to even know that they're at the right place to ask X.  They just have to ask it, and get told "you couldn't read the invisible/non-existent site descriptive text, so you're in the wrong place; go to _______."

Comment: It just seems to me that X% of StackExchange posts are made on the wrong site, and a decent chunk of that X% (though certainly not all) could be avoided if people knew there was an (obvious, like on the front page, and not at some obscure URL) way to check that they're in the right place before they post.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've had a long-standing, recurring appeal to **provide a short byline below every site title** describing succinctly what the site is about.

A lot of *"great idea!"* responses; no follow-through yet. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't the first company to do this.  I can't tell you how many enterprise sites I've encountered where I've browsed through a half-dozen pages of Dilbert mission statements and marketing double-speak, and concluded "I still haven't the slightest idea what your company does."  I am at a loss to explain this, other than perhaps the usual corporate myopia.

Answer (score 3):

> which means there is NOTHING to indicate what either one is for on the front page: no text of any sort describes what the site is about.

I can see your point, but it's not entirely true; the front page is full of questions. Their titles give a clue what kind of questions are on-topic, sufficiently (IMHO) to distinguish between Super User and Server Fault. If you doubt whether a question is on-topic or not, a single sentence is not going to help; you'll need the appropriate Help Center article.

Comment: But there's a huge overlap between SuperUser questions and StackExchange questions.  Maybe part of the problem is the overlap in content between those two sites, but whatever distinction there is between them is even more lost because of the lack of a site explanation.  Furthermore, the questions a user sees will vary highly, so while this approach may work well one day and for one user, it might not work as well on another day with a user (who can't distinguish that the set of questions they got shown look more/less super-user-y or sys-admin-y).

Comment: This is a terrible answer. The lines are very blurred when comparing certain stack exchange communities. If fact some questions can be asked on more than one stack exchange site, especially when the topic is software. A question that might be suited for Stack Overflow, might be able to be asked on Superuser, Computer Science, Database Admin, Linux, etc... At the very least, a small about link, should be provided near the title of each stack exchange community.