# Description of Stack Exchange Beta site removed after joining a site

Tags: feature-request, scope, beta-sites

When you visit the website of a beta Stack Exchange site you are not a member of, you are greeted with a nice description of the site. For example, on 
[Operations Research Beta](https://or.stackexchange.com/) you see the following:
[image]

However, once you join the site, this description goes away:

[image]

On a beta site, to my knowledge, there is no way to find the description anywhere on the site as a member.

Can we create a way to continue viewing the description of a beta site even after joining?

On non beta sites, you can see the description at the top right:

[image]

So this appears to only be a Beta website feature.

Comment: Isn't that description also used in the [tour](https://or.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: @rene Is the tour accessible other than knowing the endpoint "/tour"? In other words, if I am at "or.stackexchange.com" can I find the description?

Comment: Click on the Question Mark icon in the topbar (second icon from the right), the first option in the menu drop down is the Tour. In that same menu you'll find links to the Help center, What is Meta and the About Us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That description is also mentioned in the [Tour](https://or.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Operations Research Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for operations research and analytics professionals, educators, and students... [boilerplate text omitted]

and the [global site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

> #### Operations Research
>
> Q&A for operations research and analytics professionals, educators, and students

You can usually find a more explicit definition of the scope in the [Help Center](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

You might also be interested in this recent feature request: [I should be able to tell what a Stack Exchange site is about from its front page, even when logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338526/295232).

---

The widget you mention on Code Golf & Coding Challenges is actually an exception; only a handful of sites in the network have that. Other examples are [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) and various religious sites, e.g. [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), and [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/).